# Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, visual-studio-2015

My Code is :-

```
var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(pathUrl +"/auth/Login", 
                                  new StringContent(postData,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
```

Exception thrown:

> 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in
>   mscorlib.dll

Stack Trace:

> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

After I upgraded from Visual-Studio-2012 to Visual-Studio-2015,this exception start to come.

Comment: Are you sending multiple requests ?

Comment: @viveknuna No for single request only this exception is coming.

Comment: check whether url ir correct and user is authorized ?

Comment: @viveknuna before upgrade of Visual-Studio it was working fine.

Comment: @gorakh provide more detail about exception like error message and stacktrace.

Comment: @viveknuna I have added the Stack Trace error in question itself.